# Google pub/sub ERROR com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a snowplow enricher application hosted in GKE consuming messages from google pub/sub subscription and the enricher application is throwing the below error.

I can see **num_undelivered_messages** count spiking(going above 50000) in the pub/sub subscription 3-4 times a day and i presume these error messages are occurring as enricher application is unable to fetch messages from the mentioned subscription.

Why is the application unable to connect to pub/sub subscription at times?

Any help is really appreciated.

```
Apr 12, 2022 12:30:32 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$2 onFailure
WARNING: failed to send operations
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: 502:Bad Gateway
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1050)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1176)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:969)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:760)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:545)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: 502:Bad Gateway
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
... 15 more
```

Comment: For how long do the spikes last? Do they correlate with the error messages like the ones you posted? How many instances of your subscriber are running? Do they all have errors at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The accumulation of messages in the subscriptions suggests that your subscribers are not keeping up with the flow of messages.

To monitor your subscribers, you can create a dashboard that contains backlog metrics: `num_undelivered_messages` and `oldest_unacked_message_age` (age of the oldest unacked message in the subscription's backlog) aggregated by resource for all your subscription.

- If both the `oldest_unacked_message` and `num_undelivered_messages` are growing it is because the subscribers are not keeping up with the message volume.

  **Solution:** Add more subscriber threads/ machines and look for any bugs in your code which might prevent acknowledging messages.
- If there is a steady, small backlog size with a steadily growing `oldest_unacked_message_age`, there may be a small number of messages that cannot be processed. This can be due to the messages getting stuck.

  **Solution:** Check your application logs to understand whether some messages are causing your code to crash. It's unlikely—but possible —that the offending messages are stuck on Pub/Sub rather than in your client.
- If the `oldest_unacked_message_age` exceeds the subscription's message retention duration there are high chances of data loss; in that case the best option is to set up alerts to fire before subscription's message retention duration lapses.

Comment: Thanks sakshi for explaining this, subscriber application autoscaling has been enabled and would scale based on the message flow in pub/sub subscription, and i am unable to find any relevant logs on the subscriber application end.